# JavaScript to find a value from a field

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the value of a specif field on a web page , I have tried everything I know and I still can't seam to get it to work . Any help would be greatly appreciated.  the code from the page is

```
<meta property="location:latitude" content="35.58013861241607">
```

I need to grab the content field but not sure how to do that, I tried .text() and a few other ways but i just can't figure it out . Thanks again for any help

Comment: You tried calling `.text()` on what?

Comment: $('location:latitude').text();  is what I tried . it came up as undefined

Comment: $("meta[property='location:latitude']").attr("content");

Comment: So you're using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks keja that worked, I didn't know I could use attr('content')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An html meta tag does not have a `text` method. However, in JavaScript, there is a method for obtaining an attribute.

Try using `getAttribute`.

```js
var meta = document.querySelector("meta[property='location:latitude']");
var par = document.getElementById("content");

content.innerHTML = "Content: " + meta.getAttribute("content");
```

```html
<meta property="location:latitude" content="35.58013861241607">

<p id="content"></p>
```

Here's the similar code in jQuery

```js
$("#content").html("Content: " + $("meta[property='location:latitude']").attr("content"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta property="location:latitude" content="35.58013861241607">

<p id='content'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the `meta` tag using `querySelector` or `getElementsByTagName`, and then using `getAttribute`. How about something like this?

```js
var element = document.querySelector('meta[property="location:latitude"]');
var content = element.getAttribute("content");
console.log("content: " + content);
```

```html
<meta property="location:latitude" content="35.58013861241607">
```

If you're using jQuery, try this:

```
var element = $('meta[property="location:latitude"]');
var content = element.attr("content");
console.log("content: " + content);
```